# How to use xcopy to copy a file into a non existing directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy

As a part of an automated script, I am trying to do achieve something like this in windows command prompt:

```
xcopy /I /Y resources\xyz\pqrs.txt %TEMP%\resources\xyz\pqrs.txt.bak
```

In %TEMP%, there is no resources directory.

This is the interactive output, that I get:

```
Does C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\resources\xyz\pqrs.txt.bak specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

The whole thing is that I want to create a directory and copy file without interaction.

If I use a mkdir, I will have to extract the directory path out before using mkdir. I was just wondering if its possible to use xcopy to achieve mkdir+copy at the same time.

[xcopy reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) for all.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

If the destination path ends with a backslash it will automatically be treated as a directory:

```
xcopy /f C:\abc\file1 C:\abc\newfolder\file2
```

will ask

```
Does C:\abc\newfolder\file2 specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? f
```

but

```
xcopy /f C:\abc\file1 C:\abc\newfolder0\newfolder1\newfolder2\
```

will just do the right thing.

Comment: Doesn't that end up with the same shortcoming as, "*If I use a mkdir, I will have to extract the directory path out before using mkdir,*" wants to avoid? Even trying it in place of a `mkdir` I received a "Invalid path" error.

Comment: I missed the ``.bak`` part of OP question. To both create a destination directory **and** change the destination filename the pipe trick above must be used.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

echo d| xcopy /f C:\abc\file1 C:\abc\newfolder\file2

Comment: Just to clarify, echo d| answers to create a directory while echo f| to create a file.

Comment: Really? Do you know why? Is there a solution for other languages? Is it because of the options first letter in the xcopy command? If so, all you have to do is replace in 'echo x|' the x for the appropriate first letter.